# Get (Solspace) calendar occurences sorted by date

Tags: calendar, solspace-calendar

I want to get all occurrences of a single calendar and sort them by the occurrence start date.
The reason why I want to do this is because I want to create an occurrence details page. To do that I need the occurrence ID, the calendar:cal tag does not seem to give me the occurrence id when printing out a single occurrence. I have tried the calendar:occurrences tag, but I cannot get that one to sort the occurrences by occurence_start date. I have tried using the default orderby and sort options to accomplish the sorting, but to no avail.

How can I do this? What are my options?

Comment: have you tried orderby="event_start_date"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I highly recommend having a look at this documentation page explaining the differences between some of the more common Calendar tags. Always useful:

http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/getting_started/

In detail, if you're looking to create a **chronological list of events/occurrences**, use **`{exp:calendar:cal}`**. This is the only tag that will make the necessary calculations to list your occurrences in chronological order. Each occurrence will be listed chronologically, with `{event_start_date}` displaying the start date of each occurrence:

```
{exp:calendar:cal 
   date_range_start="1 month ago" 
   date_range_end="+1 month"
   pad_short_weeks="n"}
   {events}
       [{event_id}] {event_title} - {event_start_date format="%Y-%m-%d"}<br />
   {/events}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

Occurrences do not have their own occurrence_id unless the occurrence is edited in the Control Panel. By default the ID is the same as the "master" event_id set up in the "Calendar: Events" channel entry form.

To print out information about a single occurrence (for a specific day, for example), a good solution is to pass three elements in the URL:

- The start date
- The end date (if different from the start date)
- The "master" event_id

For example, if you want to display occurrence data for 2013-08-19 (for master event "123"), make a URL like this:

```
http://mysite.com/calendar/event/2013/08/09/123
```

...and use {exp:calendar:cal} to "zoom in" on that occurrence:

```
<h3>Occurrence details:</h3>
{exp:calendar:cal 
   date_range_start="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-{segment_5}" 
   date_range_end="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-{segment_5}"
   pad_short_weeks="n"
   event_id="{segment_6}"
}
   {events}
       {event_title} occurrence data:<br />
       Starts on  {event_start_date format="%Y-%m-%d"}<br />
       Ends on  {event_end_date format="%Y-%m-%d"}<br />
   {/events}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

Of course you can change the structure of the URL to be

```
http://mysite.com/calendar/event/2013-08-09/123
```

...and use {exp:calendar:cal} accordingly:

```
{exp:calendar:cal 
   date_range_start="{segment_3}" 
   date_range_end="{segment_3}"
   pad_short_weeks="n"
   event_id="{segment_4}"
}
// the rest of the code...
```

Comment: I've found the above answer very helpful, thanks! But could you please expand on your comment about "making a URL like this"? I'd assume that in the main list of events, you'd link each list item with an HREF tag; then what would be the exact URL specifics in that tag to pass the date along? Thanks very much!

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. If you have comments or clarification questions, please add them as comments to the question or answer they refer to.

Comment: @JeremyGimbel Actually, that *is* an answer. The answer was that the wrong tag was being used to accomplish the OP's goal. Guess I could have worded it as "{exp:calendar:occurrences} isn't the optimal tag for creating a list of occurrences ordered by start date (chronological)". :)

Comment: @JennyT. Creating a URL to point to your event detail page, using the structure suggested above, could be done in more than one way, but here's one example: `<a href="{path='event/details'}/{event_start_date format="%Y/%m/%d"}/{event_id}">{event_title} details</a>`. Of course, it all depends if you want to make the year, month and date separate segments or not in your URL. :)