# Calendar - Shows event beginning date and not the current event date

Tags: solspace-calendar

I am running Solspace Calendar 1.8.9 on EE 2.8.1 and I am having an issue with recurring events not reflecting the next event date, but instead showing the first event date.

Example: On this [page](http://opteracreative.com/~mac/calendar/category/33), the first event is "Southern Fried Comics..." with a date of 7.7.2014. However, if you click on the title it takes you to the event [details page](http://opteracreative.com/~mac/calendar/event/southern-fried-comics-late-bloomer-and-metaphasis) where the Date is displayed as July 2.

Here is the code on the first page:

```
{exp:calendar:cal 
                    date_range_start="today" 
                    orderby="event_start_date" 
                    category="{segment_3}" 
                    show_months="3" 
                    dynamic="off" 
                    event_limit="10" 
                    paginate="bottom"
                    }
                            <div class="event-summary">
                                    <div class="details">
                                        <span class="event-title"><a href="{path='calendar/event'}/{event_url_title}">{event_title}</a></span>
                                        {exp:trunchtml chars="100" inline="..." }{event_summary}{/exp:trunchtml}
                                        <span class="local-time">{event_location} | {event_start_date format="%g:%i%a"} | {contact_phone}</span>
                                        <p class="learn-more" ><a href="{path='calendar/event'}/{event_url_title}">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
                                    </div><!-- end .details -->

                                    <div class="date-details">
                                        <span class="month-day">{event_start_date format="%n.%j"}</span><br />
                                        <span class="year">{event_start_date format="%Y"}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearer"></div>
                            </div><!-- end .event-summary -->

                                    {paginate}
                                        <div class="pagination">
                                            Page <span class="this-page">{current_page}</span> of {total_pages} pages &nbsp; {pagination_links}
                                        </div>
                                    {/paginate}

{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

And here is the code for the event page:

```
{exp:calendar:events 
                    limit="1" 
                    event_name="{segment_3}"
                    dynamic="no" }
                        <h3>{event_title}</h3>

                        <div id="event-details">

                            <h4>When:</h4>
                                <p>
                              {if event_recurs}
                                 {exp:calendar:date
                                    base_date="{segment_4}-{segment_5}-{segment_6}"
                                    output_date="today"
                                 }
                                    {date format="%l, %F %j"} @ {event_start_date format="%g:%i%a"}
                                 {/exp:calendar:date}
                              {if:else}
                                 {event_start_date format="%l, %F %j @ %g:%i%a"}
                              {/if}
                           </p>

                            <h4>Location:</h4>
                            <p>{event_location}
                                {if event_address}<br />
                                    {event_address}
                                {/if}
                            </p>

                            <h4>Admission:</h4>
                            <p>{admission}</p>

                            <h4>Contact</h4>
                            <p>{contact_phone}</p>

                    {/exp:calendar:events}  

                    <div id="more-events">
                                <h4>More Events</h4>

                        {exp:calendar:cal 
                            calendar_id="11" 
                            date_range_start="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-{segment_5}"
                            date_range_end="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-{segment_5}"
                            pad_short_weeks="n"
                            event_limit="3" 
                            dynamic="off"}
                            <div class="event-mini">
                                <span>{event_start_date format="%m.%d"}</span>
                                <p><a href="{path='calendar/event'}/{event_id}/">{event_title}</a></p>
                             <div class="clearer"></div>
                            </div>
                        {/exp:calendar:cal}

                        <p  class="more-events"><a href="{site_url}calendar/">{ More Events }</a></p>
                    </div><!-- #more-events -->

                        </div><!-- end #event-details -->

                        <div id="event-full-description">
                        {exp:calendar:events orderby="title" sort="asc" limit="1" event_name="{segment_3}" date_range_start="today" show_months="6" dynamic="off"}
                                {event_summary}
    {/exp:calendar:events}
```

How can I change the code so it reflects the correct date?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{exp:calendar:cal}` for your details page. This is the tag that will display only the occurrences of an event within the timeframe set in `date_range_start=""` and `date_range_end=""` (also add `pad_short_weeks="n"`!).

Building an events detail page with a specific date "zoomed in" has been answered in another thread, with the full solution posted here: [Get (Solspace) calendar occurences sorted by date](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12754/get-solspace-calendar-occurences-sorted-by-date/12824#12824)

(I believe *ExpressionEngine® Answers* doesn't like links to solutions and prefers full inline answers. If that's necessary, I can post the same answer from that thread here.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I am done asking calendar questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the 'occurrences' tag within the loop to display the specific event occurrence that you want.
http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/occurrences/
Use event_range_start and event_range_end to select the proper occurence. The date value you're using in the above code is only for the date used on the first entry.

```
{exp:calendar:occurrences
    date_range_start="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-{segment_5}"
    date_range_end="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-{segment_5}"
    dynamic="off"
}
```